# Debian Internet Connection Cannot Access Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, internet-connection

I'm have a problem, I cannot access the internet. I'm using a dell inspiron 6400 with debian kernel 3.2 installed. My windows manager is xfce4. I was never able to figure out the wired network, however at my home I had the wireless network working just fine. I'm at my mom's house now, and I can't get the wireless to connect. I connected with wicd, and it says that I'm connected, however I can't access the internet(seems very strange).

I have a CS assignment due before I get home, so I need to figure this out very quickly. Is there anything I can do to determine my connectivity?

Thanks for the help guys, just ask if you need any additional info.

EDIT: IT'S MY DNS, I just connected to google in my browser by typing in 74.125.224.70! So at least I have internet. Will somebody help explain why my DNS isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Your resolv.conf file is not correct.

Do the following

1. Open a terminal
  2.

> sudo -i

Open the following file with vi - if you need instructions on how to use vi type the following command

> man vi

3.

> vi /etc/resolv.conf

4. fill in the following

> ```
> nameserver 8.8.8.8
> nameserver the one provided by your internet service provider
> ```

Esc to exit typing

Press shift + :wq

This will write and quit the file. type in

> ping www.google.com

BOOM!